# Is it possible to initialise an ES6 class with data when using native getters and setters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter-setter, es6-class

With this ES6 class:

```
class DatasetController {
  constructor() {
    this._dataset = [];
    return this;
  }
  get dataset() {
    return this._dataset;
  }
  set dataset(data) {
    if (data) {
      this._dataset = {
        a: data.a,
      }
    }
    return this._dataset;
  }
}
```

is it possible to initialise instance creation with data for this._dataset?

such as:

```
class DatasetController {
  constructor(data) {
    this._dataset = [];

    // set data here from arg?
    // this.dataset(data) will override the set dataset method

    return this;
  }
  // ...
}
```

How can I consume the class `set` method inside the constructor as well as inside subsequent instance methods in the future?

Comment: Did you try `this.dataset = data` in the constructor (after adding the `data` argument to the constructor)?

Comment: it overrides the getter @nnnnnn

Comment: Really? It worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: try `get` again after you clobber it

Comment: It works perfectly for me with `this.dataset = data;` (as long as `data` has `a` defined, obviously). No clobbering. Can you demonstrate with a code snippet why you think it gets clobbered?

Comment: "*How can I consume the class set method…*" You want to eat it? What does "consume" mean in this context?

Comment: @Amadan - even if the `data` argument has no `a` property it still works in that a value is stored (but that value is `undefined`), unless `data` is itself `null` or `undefined`. But definitely no clobbering of the get method: using the getter after that works fine.

Comment: out of interest: is there a reason to return `this` in the constructor?